# UItableViewRowAction custom

Tags: swift

how to add "add" button into the tableviewcell?
I'm using array to add value into it, then the problem is, how to add them together and sum it up and show in new view controller by using the UItableViewRowAction? 
Can show an example? using swift2

Comment: Do you want to add button to your table view cell and on click of the row you want to navigate it to another view controller? If yes then why are you adding the button ?

Comment: i mean while sliding the cell while have "add" features. Another way to say is that would like to have something like music playlist which can add songs then after add selected songs then add them to a new playlist.